# ipad no touch gestures but still clickable

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I have a webpage for my ipad that has clickable buttons.

But sometimes people have trouble clicking because they drag their finger and it makes the page 'scroll'.

My pages are the size of the screen so I don't need to be able to scroll. Is there a way to eliminate the scroll/movement on a webpage via html/css?

Thanks.

Comment: The app im using to display the page allows me to disable touch gestures but then I can't click... never developed for ipads and wanted to see if the community here had any easy knowledge on this.

Comment: The other questions I have found are about videos and involved .js or something more than css

Comment: `body { overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using .js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener(
'touchmove',
function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
},
false
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable scrolling, you can simply use the following jQuery code:

```
$(window).bind('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault() });
```